# Admob recieves request but not print ad

Tags: android, admob

Time ago i made an app and I added ads to it with admob without a problem. Now I made a new one but now the ads show this error `Ad failed to load : 3` I know is an admob thing but its been a week since i made this app and im waiting for the ads. I decided to make a new version of the one that the ads well implemented, and just by adding an activity now any ad is working in that new version. 
How this is happening? How much do i have to wait and what can i do?
I've seen sometimes is a problem with adsense, so you have to link it with admob, the problem is that when i try to link them i get to this webpage where is unable to login and even if you are already logged it doesnt do anything https://admob.google.com/home/